# Angular 2 : Type ChildComponent is a part of the declarations of 2 modules : parent1Module and Parent2Module

Tags: angular

I have 2 parent component and 1 child component. And my project structure is below:

```
app
   -> app.module.ts
   -> app.component.ts
   -> app.routing.module.ts
parentComponent1
   -> parent1.module.ts
   -> parent1.component.ts
parentComponent2
   -> parent2.module.ts
   -> parent2.component.ts
childComponent
   -> child.module.ts
   -> child.component.ts
```

Now my problem is when i am using child componet's selector in parentComponent1 and parentComponent2 as :

```
<child-component [name]="parent1"></child-component>
```

And importing child module in both parent component as :

parent1.module.ts--

```
 @NgModule({
          imports:[ChildModule],
           declarations:[ChildComponent]
})
----
---- 
and so on....
```

And same in parentComponent2's Moudle as :

parent2.module.ts--

```
 @NgModule({
              imports:[ChildModule],
               declarations:[ChildComponent]
    })
    ----
    ---- 
    and so on....
```

Now when i starts my project, my default routes go to parentComponent1 and there is no error in console and it works fine, but when i go to parentComponent2, then the error comes in console as :

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Type ChildComponent part of the
>   declarations of 2 modules: Parent1Module and Parent2Module! Please
>   consider moving ChildComponent to a higher module that imports
>   Parent1Module and Parent2Module . You can also create a new NgModule
>   that exports and includes ChildComponent then import that NgModule in
>   Parent1Module and Parent2Module

.

Please help me out what wrong i am doing here.

Comment: You are importing Child in Parent ?  Seems something wrong in logical structure.

Answer (score 8):

Use this solution

You should not declarations a component in more than one NgModule, you could export in one NgModule, then import this NgModule in other NgModule.

**child.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[...],
  declarations:[ChildComponent],
  exports:[ChildComponent]
})
```

**parent1.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[ChildModule],
  declarations:[...]
})
```

**parent2.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports:[ChildModule],
  declarations:[...]
})
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Tiep Phan for the clean and accurate answer :) Now its working fine.

Comment: glad to help you!